# How to check a Bluetooth module's UUID number?

Tags: bluetooth, uuid, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am using a 8265A 8265NGW module with Jetson Nano.
I am trying to connect my Jetson Nano.

How to check my bluetooth UUID?

Answer (score 1):

Try running

```
bluetoothctl info
```

For more info, see this question on SE.U&L, [What are the UUIDs listed by `bluetoothctl info`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/623558/97255)